# How do we use Python generated protobuf codes in to python code?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

I have installed protobuf in Python 3.4 and i pushed the compiled code `pb_x_pb2.py` into python34 folder. When i enter `import  pb_x_pb2.py` it shows the following error.

```
>>> import pb_interface_pb2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#21>", line 1, in <module>
    import pb_interface_pb2
  File "C:\Python34\pb_interface_pb2.py", line 5, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import reflection
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\reflection.py", line 68, in <module>
    from google.protobuf.internal import python_message
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\internal\python_message.py", line 848
    except struct.error, e:
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Did you compile for Python 3? The syntax looks like Python 2.

Comment: Oh!!! It means I can only use python 2.7??

Comment: Protobuffer should be supported under 3.x, too. But if you compiled for Python 2.x, the result will only run under 2.x. How did you compile the Protobuffer file to Python?

Comment: Thank you.Compilation is done using the binary protoc.

Answer (score 2):

Protobuf doesn't really support python 3.x. For the imported libraries, try `pip install protobuf-py3`, a python 3 port of the package. You can also run the `2to3.py` script from the `Pythonxx\Tools\Scripts` folder on the generated file.

Another option would be to download the newest version of the sources, and compile them yourself. I believe that the newest version is mostly compatible with both 2.x and 3.x

Comment: I have tried in python2.7 version itself but still facing same issue.I installed protobuf using 'pip install protobuf'. But when i do 'import protobuf' in idle it shows Import error that no module available. To use that compiled python protobuf code I trust protobuf should be imported. Can you please tell the steps clearly to use the protobuf code, since Iam new here I am unable to follow you.

Comment: It sounds like you are not using the idle from the same installation as where you installed it. Do you have multiple versions of python installed?